# Why sometimes Kafka Messaging Queue returns no message when writing Integration Test?

Tags: java, junit, apache-kafka, micronaut-kafka

I have am trying to write Integration test for Kafka Messaging in my application. When I run my tests sometimes they pass and sometimes they fail. When they fail, below line in test class fails to return any message. I am not sure why it returns message sometimes and sometimes it does not. Any help in resolving is greatly appreciated. All the configurations are in yml file.

```
Map<String, MessageResponse> message = messageResponseTestListener.getMessages();
```

Producer

```
@KafkaClient
public interface MessageRequestTestProducer {

     @Topic("${kafka.messageRequestTopic}")
     Single<RecordMetadata> sendMessageRequest(@KafkaKey String id, MessageRequest messageRequest);
}
```

Consumer

```
@Singleton
@KafkaListener(groupId = "test", offsetReset = OffsetReset.EARLIEST)
public class MessageResponseTestListener {

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    private Map<String, MessageResponse> messages = new HashMap<>();

    @Topic("${kafka.messageResponseTopic}")
    public Single<MessageResponse> eventOccurred(@KafkaKey String key, Single<MessageResponse> recordSingle) {
        return recordSingle.doOnSuccess(record -> {
                    messages.put(key, record);
                    latch.countDown();
                }
        );

    }

    public Map<String, MessageResponse> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

KafkaBaseTest

```
public class KafkaTestBase implements TestPropertyProvider{

protected static KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3"));

@Override
public Map<String, String> get()
{
    return null;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Map<String, String> getProperties()
{
    Map<String, String> propertyOverrideMap = new HashMap();
    propertyOverrideMap.put("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka.getBootstrapServers());

    return propertyOverrideMap;
}

static {
    kafka.start();
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@Inject
MessageRequestTestProducer messageRequestTestProducer;

@Inject
MessageResponseTestListener messageResponseTestListener;

@Test
void test() throws InterruptedException {

    TEST("Message Testing Kafka version");

    String id = "123";
    MessageRequest messageRequest = buildCorrectRequest();
    messageRequestTestProducer.sendMessageRequest(id, messageRequest).blockingGet();

    messageResponseTestListener.getLatch().await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WHEN("Message event received");

    Map<String, MessageResponse> message = messageResponseTestListener.getMessages();

    THEN("Message is produced");

    assertTrue(message.containsKey(id));
    assertEquals(buildExpectedMessageResponse(), message.get(cdrId));

}
```

Comment: It's going to be difficult to debug this, as a lot will depend on the producer and consumer configs and other actors on your Kafka environment. Seemingly you're purging your topic in between runs (otherwise `OffsetReset.EARLIEST` would rewind and find messages from previous runs). I would however look at settings such as the [producer linger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521737) config - perhaps 2 seconds isn't sufficient for your test consumer.

Comment: If you're running your tests against an actual Kafka cluster, there's high probability your tests will fail occasionally. Start an embedded broker like the Kafka project itself does for its own tests

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Sorry I am new to Kafka. Could you please explain what you mean by "starting an embedded broker like Kafka project"?

Comment: Embedded == "in memory". Most popular is probably spring one https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-Kafka-testing  Or look at micronaut itself https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kafka/blob/master/kafka/src/test/groovy/io/micronaut/configuration/kafka/AbstractEmbeddedServerSpec.groovy#L11 (uses https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am using the embedded one.. I have updated the question itself with implementation of KafkaTestBase class. Is that what you meant? I still am getting the same issue.

Comment: @StuartLC I have also tried to increase the time from 2 sec to 5 & 10 sec respectively but still am unable to get the response on consumer. I do not fully understand the producer linger link you have provided as I am no where setting any batch sizes.

Comment: I'm not sure what `implements TestPropertyProvider` gives you, but okay, so you are using Testcontainers... Maybe your "await 2 seconds" call is too short for the tests? Hard to really say

Comment: The producer itself, by default, waits (or lingers) for additional information to be produced. Kafka doesn't immediately send every record to the broker

Comment: @OneCricketeer So, then for how long should we wait for the producer to send the record and consumer to consume it?

Comment: I'm not sure. Your `.blockingGet()` should handle that on its own

Comment: Worth pointing out that using a Hashmap is probably a anti-pattern anyway. Use a KTable instead and `groupByKey` from a KStream

Comment: What do you mean by " '''.blockingGet()''' should handle that on its own"?